# Adjusting Overlapping Dates and Applying Other Rules

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to design a `SELECT` query that will modify some dates in a subset of "**activity**" records for each person in a table of data.

Each person is identified uniquely using "PersonID" and then each activity record using "RecordID".

Each subset of activity records a person has will also have dates against the "Start Date" and "End Date" fields.

For example, data like this (sorted by start date then longest duration):

[image]

(I've added the yellow bars to give an idea of some of the overlap and gaps between sets of dates).

Where I work, we have a task that involves adding a maximum of 1 "**claim**" record to associate with each of these activity records. The claim records have their own Start Date and End Date, but each claim record must:

- Not cover a duration outside of the Start Date and End Date of the activity record it's being attached to.
- Not overlap with the duration of any other claim record in the person's subset of claim records
- Have a duration of at least 1 month, defined as either: starting on the first day of the month and ending on the last day of the month (e.g. 1/12/2018 to 31/12/2018), or starting in a month but ending in a different month (e.g. 31/12/2018 to 1/1/2019).

This is because the claim records are validated against the activity records (by an external validation tool we have no control over).

So, based on the example above, the query might output the following efficient set of dates for each activity record to use as claim records:

[image]

A brief run-down of what would happen on each record:

> **Record 1**: For claim record 1, it used the original dates from the activity records, i.e. create a claim record that covers the entire
>   activity period. If working through the records in the sort order
>   described, it would make sense that it simply claims the full activity
>   period for the first claim record for each person's subset of activity
>   records.
>
> **Record 2**: For claim record 2, `NULL`s have be supplied as there is no period to claim on this activity that hasn't already been claimed
>   in record 1.
>
> **Record 3**: For claim record 3, the start date has been set to 1/12/2018, because that is the earliest date to claim from that is
>   both within this activity period and after the end month of the last
>   claim (i.e. record 1's 25/11/2019 end date).
>
> The end date has been set to 31/12/2018. You may wonder why it is not
>   set to the activity's original end date of 23/1/2019. If you look
>   ahead to record 5, setting record 3's end date to 23/1/2019 would mean
>   setting record 5's start date to 1/2/2019, and it's end date would be
>   4/2/2019, which is not long enough to make a claim. So it would be
>   more efficient to stop record 3 in December so record 5 can claim both
>   January AND February. This may be hard to script though!
>
> **Record 4**: For claim record 4, `NULL`s have be supplied as there is no period to claim on this activity that hasn't already been claimed
>   in previous claim records.
>
> **Record 5**: For claim record 5, the start date has been set to 1/1/2019. See record 3 for an explanation of why.
>
> **Record 6**: For claim record 6, it used the original dates from the activity records. This was just to illustrate that not all activity
>   records will overlap.

I'm not too sure how to approach this. I've looked at some CTE examples, but nothing that seems to match what I'm trying to do (perhaps too ambitious.. particularly the record 3 & 5 scenario?)

Any help / examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Way too much uncertain. E.g. why not to exclude r3  as r1 + r5 totally covers r3?

Comment: @Serg true, that would work too. As long as the query doesn't miss claiming a month that has activity then it'll have done its job. But like you say, there's probably too much uncertainty to guarantee this.